# Error in recur call in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I am trying to read numbers from input and printing them back in Clojure till I read the number 42. A really basic thing to make sure I know how to read input. Taken from [codechef](https://www.codechef.com/problems/TEST)

I have written this program. Might not be good clojure.

```
(defn universe
  []
  (let [num (line-seq (java.io.BufferedReader. *in*))]
    (if (not= num 42)
      (do
        (println num)
        (recur (universe))
        )
      )
    )
  )
```

My understanding is that `line-seq` lazily evaluates from whatever reader is given. In this case the standard input.

So I have let it be num. Then if num is not 42 I print it and then recursively call universe. But it throws exception

```
Mismatched argument count to recur, expected: 0 args, got: 1,
```

I have seen an [example](https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/381614) and recur does take an argument. Looking at the [official documentation](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/recur) I couldn't see the syntax for this. So why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`recur` does not take the name of the location to recur to. Instead the recur special form jumps back up to the closest function or `loop` expression, whichever is closer. It then passes it different arguments. This lets you go through the same block of code repeatedly as you work through the data, and there is no function call overhead.

In your case it's recurring up to the function call:

```
(defn universe [] ...
```

and trying to pass it an argument, which fails because universe, the function, does not accept any arguments. perhaps you intended to put a `loop` expression around the if?

```
user> (defn universe
        []
        (let [numbers (line-seq (java.io.BufferedReader. *in*))]
          (loop [numbers numbers]
            (let [num (first numbers)]
              (if (not= (Integer/parseInt num) 42)
                (do
                  (println num)
                  (recur (rest numbers))))))))
#'user/universe
user> (universe)
3   ;; typed 3 
nil ;; typed 42
```

or where you intending to recur back to the top of the function, in which case just call `(recur)` instead of `(recur universe)`

Comment: The logic makes sense but it's not working by either of the 2 ways. Just calling recur instead of (recur universe) gets a infinite loop. I have stop the REPL. Even adding a println after the let does not give me any output. Putting a loop as you have done givthes a CastException of lazySeq to String. I think it might be because the (first numbers) is the argument value. So tried adding another let in the loop to get the first. Then got another infinite loop.  Using Clojure 1.7 with OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0_79-b14 on Ubuntu 14.04. Just in case that matters.

Comment: Surely *there is no function call overhead* for any `recur` call, whether to a `loop` or to a function form.

Comment: Your logic looks faulty. The `loop` is set up with `num` bound to `(first numbers)`, yet the `recur` binds it to `(rest numbers)`, surely not compatible. Besides. `numbers` hence `(rest numbers)` is invariant in the `loop`.

Comment: @Thumbnail oops I pasted in totally the wrong chunk of code :-/ and didn't read my post before clicking. Sorry about that and thanks for pointing it out. I pasted in the output from the repl this time so it should work